# Change display name on Google Docs invitation to edit

Tags: google-docs, google-drive-sharing

Whenever I share a Google Docs/Sheets etc it always shows

> email@example.com has invited you to edit

I would like it to show

> My name has invited you to edit

I know this is possible, but I do not know how to do this. Please, can someone assist?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but there is no way to customize those emails directly. The only workaround would be to uncheck the 'notify people' box & send a separate email with the link